# Update gradle version to 5.1.1, but kapt not work

Tags: android, gradle, kotlin, kapt

It was all work fine in gradle version 4.5, but when I update to 5.1.1, the processor that extends `AbstractProcessor` seems did not was execute, not any log and nothing was generated in dir: build/generated/source/kapt.

gradle version: 4.5; gradle plugin: 3.1.2. work

gradle version: 5.1.1; gradle plugin: 3.4.1. not work

PS: see git https://github.com/drumge/android-kvo

Comment: try this --> delete build folder, invalidate cashes/Restart, clean and rebuild project.

Comment: had try all of those 'delete build folder, invalidate cashes/Restart, clean and rebuild project' , but not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this same problem on upgrade of Android Studio (3.3 -> 3.4) (This upgrades gradle from 4.10.1 -> 5.1.1).
I'm using kapt, and an annotation processor I built as a java module. Everything worked fine before the update.

My solution was:
 - Upgrade `com.google.auto.service:auto-service` to `1.0-rc6`
 - Add `annotationProcessor "com.google.auto.service:auto-service:1.0-rc6"` to the annotation processor's build.gradle file.

Found my answer via these:
- https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/7941
- https://github.com/ishaigor/annotation-processor-sample/commit/d7645914b9f53a5f350c7098973f3554c48e75d8

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

In your `build.graddle` module app include this : `apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'`

Comment: There is `apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'` in my `build.graddle`. It work fine with `gradle version: 4.5; gradle plugin: 3.1.2`, but not work with `gradle version: 5.1.1; gradle plugin: 3.4.1`